# When are quotients of the polynomial ring local?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra

Let $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,...,x_n]$ denote the polynomial ring in $n$-variables with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$. This ring is not local, because (for example) any ideal of the form $(x_1 - a_1,...,x_n-a_n)$ is maximal.

Let $I$ be an ideal. Is anything known about under what conditions the quotient $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,...,x_n]/I$ is local? We know that the quotient is an integral domain if and only if $I$ is a prime ideal, and we know that the quotient is a field if and only if $I$ is a maximal ideal.

We also know that the localization of any ring away from a prime ideal is local, with the maximal ideal in the localization being the image of the prime ideal in question.

What else is known? Are there known sufficient/necessary conditions on $I$?

Comment: This is true if and only if $\sqrt{I}$ is a maximal ideal.

Comment: By the way, the ideal $(x_1-a_1,\dots,x_n-a_n)$ is not maximal.

Comment: @Mohan Does that probably work for any UFD (or is Noetherianness needed?)

Comment: @Mohan thank you for your answer! Where can I find a proof of this?

Comment: @JWL I see. I think I'm confused. Would those ideals be maximal if we replace $\mathbb{Z}$ by an algebraically closed field? Is much known about maximal ideals in the case of $\mathbb{Z}$?

Comment: To explain JWL's comment, note that $\mathbb{Z}[x_1, \dots, x_n]/(x_1 - a_1, \dots, x_n - a_n) \cong \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: @rschwieb I don't think so : if $A$ is already a local UFD (for example a regular local ring), then $A/(0)$ is obviously local though $\sqrt{(0)}$ may not be maximal.

Comment: Please look up Jacobson rings. Any prime ideal in a Jacobson ring is the intersection of all maximal ideals containing it. Rest should be easy, once you prove that $\mathbb{Z}[x_1,\ldots, x_n]$ is Jacobson.

Comment: @Mohan I'm afraid that I am unable to proceed, even with your hint. I do not see how this gives me anything about $R/I$ being local - could you possibly provide further guidance?

Comment: If local, it has only one maximal ideal. Jacobson means all prime ideals are intersection of maximal ideals containing it. Together, thus, the ring can have only one prime ideal. So, your ring must be one where the nilradical is a maximal ideal.

Comment: Thank you very much. If you transport the first/any of your comments into an answer I'll accept it so that this can be listed as answered.